# Facebook - JavaScript SDK and saving user information to a database

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I made some research and I found that the Facebook JavaScript SDK is better than the PHP SDK. Now I take the user information with JavaScript like with [FQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Query_Language):

```
function fqlQuery(){
    showLoader(true);

    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        showLoader(false);

        //http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/
        var query = FB.Data.query('select name, profile_url, sex, pic_small from user where uid={0}',
                                  response.id);
        query.wait(function(rows) {
            document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML =
                'FQL Information: '+  "<br />" +
                'Your name: '      +  rows[0].name                                                            + "<br />" +
                'Your Sex: '       +  (rows[0].sex!= undefined ? rows[0].sex : "")                            + "<br />" +
                'Your Profile: '   +  "<a href='" + rows[0].profile_url + "'>" + rows[0].profile_url + "</a>" + "<br />" +
                '<img src="'       +  rows[0].pic_small + '" alt="" />' + "<br />";
         });
    });
}
```

I searched on the Internet, but I did not find anything. Is there a way to store this information to a database?

Comment: no answer to this question :S

Answer (score 0):

Javascript runs on client side and PHP runs on server side. Javascript SDK is generally used on client side, only to "*enrich*" UI, *(such as adding "Welcome X!" to screen)* not to fetch data and store an a DB.

However, If you do want to store them on a DB, you should send them from client to your server via an AJAX request, such as:

`$.post("/your/php/endpoint/here", rows)` in Jquery.

**But there is a security problem here**, user may send arbitary user info by bypassing Facebook's API. So, to store data on a server I recommend you to fetch information on server.

You can do this in two ways:

1. Get access token with JS api and send token to server and gather info on server by going to graph api.
2. [User server side authantication.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/)